# Errors compiling kingate on ubuntu11.04

Tags: ubuntu-11.04

It made some errors like this:

> KDnsCache.cpp: In member function ‘unsigned int KDnsCache::GetName(const char*)’:
>   KDnsCache.cpp:44:27: error: ‘strlen’ was not declared in this scope

Does anyone know how to resolve it? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the functions, which declarations are often implicitly included, in other header files. It can break, for example, when user has a newer version of some library. It would be good, if you fill a bug report for developers including full compilation log.

Tempoarily you can solve this error, by adding:

```
#include <string.h>
```

at the beginning of `KDnsCache.cpp`.

Comment: Hint: When talking about standard library function you can learn in which header the function lies, by typing `man strlen` in console.

Comment: If this answer will be useful to you, you can upvote/accept it.